# Register a function to window (global scope) from a require.js module?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ios7, requirejs

How can I register a function to window (global scope) from within a require.js module?

Background: Cordova / PhoneGap triggers an event to the window.handleOpenURL(url) function in case of opening the app from another app.

Without require.js, just defining the function in the global scope worked fine:

```
    function handleOpenURL(url) {
    ...
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this:

```
define([], function() {
    window.handleOpenURL = function(url) {
        // code goes here.
    };
});
```

Comment: Remeber it is only available after the module has been loaded.